# How to get device orientation via UIView reference?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to get device orientation from a ViewController. **I cannot base on**:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

because it sometimes returns orientation unknown (for example when the device lays on the table).

I just need to know **in what orientation is my current UIView displayed** (is it landscape left or landscape right). I don't need to have this value updated when orientation changes, I just want to know it, when I ask for it. Just some reference *view.orientation* ;). Is there something that would help me? I've read UIView documentation, found some reference to UIWindow, but nothing that could help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also get the device orientation from UIApplication, have you tried using

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm able to get UIKit components orientation and use it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

UIViewController has a property

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation;
```

So in your UIViewController, you can access the current orientation of the device at any time via

```
UIInterfaceOrientation myCurrentOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: Deprecated since iOS 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version

```
    let currentOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation


    if currentOrientation.isPortrait {

        print("PORTRAIT")

    } else if currentOrientation.isLandscape {

        print("LANDSCAPE")

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is the sample code to do the same. There is a variable named **deviceOrientation**, and it will answer the current orientation of device, whenever being asked.

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    deviceOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:deviceOrientation duration:0.5];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    deviceOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return TRUE;
}
```